# Ubuntu 20.04: On screen keyboard pops up whenever clicked on text input box. It should only pop up when touched

Tags: mouse, touchpad, 20.04, touchscreen, onscreen-keyboard

I've recently upgraded to *Ubuntu 20.04* from *Ubuntu 19.10*. I'm using *Lenovo Thinkpad L380*.

In 20.04, the on-screen keyboard was disabled and I enabled it by following this guide - [Use an on-screen keyboard](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-osk.html.en).

**Current Behavior**: Whenever I click (using *Mouse/Touchpad*) or touch (using *Touchscreen*) on any text-input area, the on-screen keyboard pops up.

**Desired Behavior**: The on-screen keyboard should only pop up when I touch (using *Touchscreen*) the text input area. It should not pop-up on *Mouse/Touchpad* clicks. (It was exactly like this in *Ubuntu 19.10*)